# Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, update

у меня есть таблица Tickets в ней столбцы VozAG и CursValueAG оба тип данных real

в столбце VozAG есть значение 30 а в столбце CursValueAG 0.155

мне нужно сделать update столбца VozAG сделав разделение столбцов VozAG/CursValueAG

чтобы 30/0.155=‭193.55

сделал запрос но там выходит ошибка

```
update Tickets 
set VozAG=(Select (VozAG/CursValueAG) from Tickets ) 
where CurrencyID='2' and DEALDATE between '2022-12-19' and '2022-12-19'
```

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

Подскажите пожалуйста где моя ошибка.

Comment: А подзапрос-то тут нафига? ну и определитесь уже, делить надо или умножать..

Comment: @Akina нужно сделать деление, исправил

Comment: "Subquery returned more than 1 value" - подзапрос возвращает несколько значений, а нужно, чтобы было одно значение, если вы хотите его присвоить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представьте таблицу. Подзапрос из старой таблицы рассчитывает колонку новой таблицы, и вы через `update` пытаетесь в каждую строку таблицы в ячейку `VozAG` записать эту рассчитанную колонку (**в одну ячейку записать много ячеек**). Такой `update` с подзапросом возможен только если подзапрос возвращает одно значение (в одну ячейку тогда запишется одно значение).

Тут в принципе не нужен подзапрос, просто пишите `set VozAG=VozAG/CursValueAG`:

```
update Tickets 
set VozAG = VozAG / CursValueAG
where CurrencyID='2' and DEALDATE between '2022-12-19' and '2022-12-19'
```